# "Considering …, the middle-out approach" Is this a dangling modifier?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, prepositional-phrases, modifiers, dangling-participles

I am writing my thesis and I have the following sentence:

> [***Considering*** its empirical complements together with the complexity, extensiveness and dynamics of the city logistic system,] the middle-out approach is thus adopted for the following hierarchy construction.

Now the subordinate phrase 'Considering ... logistic system' does not appear to be modifying the subject 'the middle-out approach'.

Do I need to rewrite this sentence? And if so, how could I rewrite it?

Comment: Sorry, Jeevan. ELU doesn't do proofreading. I don't really understand your text, but I'm sure you want ***complement*** (supplement), not ***compliment*** (praise).

Comment: Is this aiming at 'The middle-out approach is adopted for the following hierarchy construction after considering both its empirical complements and the complexity, extensiveness and dynamics of the city logistic system.'? Or  'The middle-out approach is adopted for the following hierarchy construction after deciding to consider (1) its empirical complements, and (2) the complexity, extensiveness and dynamics of the city logistic system, together.'?

Comment: As hinted at by Brett in his post below, *considering* is not a verb here and cannot be a dangling modifier. It is a preposition and prepositions don't have subjects, so it's impossible for the preposition to have a different subject from the verb in the main clause (in fact, the only cluase). This fact is born out in the data. This word *considering* is hardly ever used in such a way that it could be interpreted as a verb with the same subject as the verb in  a matrix clause. There is of course a participle *considering*, but it's never used as a discourse marker or with this meaning.

Comment: @Araucaria "This word considering is hardly ever used in such a way that it could be interpreted as a verb with the same subject as the verb in a matrix clause." Oh, really? How'bout "__Considering that we are being paid to do something for our country, we should have done something every day for our ..__." https://books.google.ca/books?id=2JW3vh1_FjsC&pg=PA30&dq=%22considering+that%22+%22we+have%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=5bUmVYXuGteHsQSGzIDAAQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22considering%20that%22%20%22we%20have%22&f=false

Comment: @MariusHancu Oh really? "Considering carefully how she would actually do it, she offered to take on the task" That's a participle clause. "Considering she wouldn't actually be able to do it, she was stupid to take on the task". That's a preposition phrase. The first involves a verb form which indicates simultaneity, the second is a preposition. The first type is very rare the second extremely common. Which do you reckon your example illustrates?

Answer (score 1):

If you take *considering* to be a past participle, then, you have a dangling modifier. There may be reasons, however, to think it is a preposition. Other prepositions that came from participles include *given*, *provided*, and *depending*.

Comment: thanks for your feedback.  Even if I use 'Given' (or provided...) does 'its' is associated with 'the middle-out approach'?? In reality, the 'its' is meant for 'the middle-out approach'. I tried multiple ways to make this sentence but I feel that I cannot make it correct. One way to write this could be "The middle-out approach is adopted for the following hierarchy construction due to its empirical compliments together with the complexity, extensiveness and dynamics of the city logistic system"

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can see something dangling out there:-) Possible recasts:

*Considering its empirical **complements** together with the complexity, extensiveness and dynamics of the city logistic system, **we** **adopted** the middle-out approach adopted for the following hierarchy construction.*

***In consideration of*** its empirical **complements** together with the complexity, extensiveness and dynamics of the city logistic system, the middle-out approach **is thus adopted** for the following hierarchy construction.